# Unopened favorite question reminder showing wrong count

Tags: support, bookmarks

Today when I opened my "meta stackoverflow" profile to see one of favorite question.  The reminder icons showed the count as **`76`**.  But I haven't favored so many question.

[image]

*Reminder is showing 76 but totally I have only 8 Favorites(I remember it should be 2 as these marked in yellow color in the image)*

Whereas in my stackoverflow profile it was working properly.

I'm not sure whether it is `total count of unopened favorites` throughout stack exchange account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That number does not represent the number of favorites you have. It represents the number of events that have occurred on your favorite questions since you last checked that tab. Most of that 76 probably came from that mug question. Considering probably about 40 new answers got posted since you favorited it, and who knows how many edits occurred, that probably accounted for a huge chunk of that number. The rest would have come from the other highlighted question.

Comment: Thank you, but why edits are getting counted to the reminder of favorites?  Do we need it?

Comment: Well, favoriting a question is basically your way of following it. So new edits to it can be somewhat important. For example, I've favorited several FAQs here on Meta so I can keep track of which ones get edited, and review the changes when those edits occur.

Comment: I guess usually users won't use favorites often to see edits(I used to mark questions as favorite because easy to get back whenever I get time for indepth understanding).  Can we use notification for this purpose(might be annoying) or one reminder for a question per day?